# Grafana iframe embedding won't let me log in

Tags: html, iframe, grafana

I am using Grafana on a local server and I wanted to embed it into a HTML via iframe. My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Monitoring</title>

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; URL=monitor - Panel Name.html">

  <style type="text/css">

    div#content {

    position: absolute;

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

  margin-left:-50;

  border:0;

    background-color: black;

  scrolling="no";

}

div#content iframe {

    position: absolute;

    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

  margin:0;

  border:0;

  frameborder="0";

  scrolling="no";

}

  </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<div id="content">

    <iframe src="[Grafana Link]" name="frame2" id="frame2" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" onload="" allowtransparency="false"></iframe>

</div>

<div id="block"></div>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>  </body>

</html>
```

I have set the "cookie_samesite = none" and "allow_embedding = true" in the grafana.ini file. When I open my document I see the login, but when I try to login, the page says "Login successful" but the login screen still stays.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: You mention that you're running Grafana on a local server. Is the origin a secure one (`https://...`)?